# R plotly marker/line color by value of other variable

Tags: r, plotly, colorbrewer

How can I color a line or markers in plotly according to values of another variable. I've taken for simplicity this [example](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/448200_6bb02977b4c04e0da508ac0131f71d48.html).

So I would like to have x colored according the value of z. Actually, preferably with my own custom color spectral.

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- data.frame(x <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, b = 0.1),
         y <- sin(x),
         z <- runif(41)
)

p11 <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(type = "scatter",
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            mode = "markers",
            marker = list(size = 10,
                          color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))(41))) %>% 
  layout(title = "Multicolored sine curve",
         xaxis = list(title = "x-axis"),
         yaxis = list(title = "y-axis"))
p11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(x <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, b = 0.1),
                 y <- sin(x),
                 z <- runif(41)
)

plot_ly(colors = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))(41)) %>% 
  add_trace(type = "scatter",
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            color = ~z,
            mode = "markers",
            marker = list(size = 10)) %>% 
  layout(title = "Multicolored sine curve",
         xaxis = list(title = "x-axis", showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "y-axis", showgrid = FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx works! Btw how can I fetch the colors which will be adressed to the values of z and y?

Comment: @H.berg Not sure what do you mean by fetch colors. You wanna get something like a dataframe with x,y,z, and colors as the fourth column?

Comment: I am not sure if there's an easy way, but you can look at ```pl1 %>% plotly_json()``` It has all the data used in the plot as a json.

Comment: Thx..works indeed!